# Copying tag values from one XML to another using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml files, say **file1.xml** which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root >
    <text id='a'>This is to be replaced</text>
    <note>This should not be touched</note>
    <text id='b'>This is intact</text>
</root>
```

**file2.xml** is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root >
    <text id='a'>Replacement Text</text>
    <note>This is a personal note</note>
</root>
```

I expect an output xml file of the form :

**output.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <text id='a'>Replacement Text</text>
    <note>This should not be touched</note>
    <text id='b'>This is intact</text>
</root>
```

Please help me with a xsl to get the desired output. This is not a homework and I am trying to understand xslt.

Comment: I would request you to please explain if something is missing in my question, if you mark it as a down vote.

Comment: What version of XSLT? What is the test of whether an element has it's text replaced? Is it by element name?

Comment: Thanks for the response Sean, please check the edit. I am simultaneously trying to get this work hence, came up with the restriction we need to identify if the correct element is getting replaced.

Comment: Your edit does not specify XSLT version. Please specify XLST version.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

Is this what you expect?

Comment: The choices are version 1.0 or version 2.0. And if 1.0, then client-side or server-side. It makes a difference in terms of capabilities.

Comment: So what is the actual test? Is it if elements from the two documents have the same id attribute, then replace? Or does is the test partially determined by element name?

Comment: It is based on the id of the elements. It would only get replace if the element name and id, both match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('file:///c:/temp/delete/file2.xml')/*/*[1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text[@id='a']/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="$vReps"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (the provided file1.xml):

```
<root>
    <text id='a'>This is to be replaced</text>
    <note>This should not be touched</note>
    <text id='b'>This is intact</text>
</root>
```

**and having the provided file2.xml residing in `c:\temp\delete\file2.xml`:**

```
<root>
    <text id='a'>Replacement Text</text>
    <note>This is a personal note</note>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <text id="a">Replacement Text</text>
   <note>This should not be touched</note>
   <text id="b">This is intact</text>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. Use of the standard XSLT function **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document)**.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know your XSLT processor version, then run this transform and report the results...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"> 
<xsl:output method = "text" /> 
<xsl:template match = "/" > 
 <xsl:text>Version :  </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select = "system-property('xsl:version')" /><xsl:text >&#x0A;</xsl:text> 
 <xsl:text>Vendor  :  </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select = "system-property('xsl:vendor')" /><xsl:text >&#x0A;</xsl:text> 
 <xsl:text>URL     :  </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select = "system-property('xsl:vendor-url')" /><xsl:text >&#x0A;</xsl:text> 
 <xsl:text>MS ver  :  </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select = "system-property('msxsl:version')" /><xsl:text >&#x0A;</xsl:text> 
 </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

## XSLT 1.0 Solution

This is not tested, but it should work...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:param name="url-of-file2" />
<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document($url-of-file2)" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@id]">
  <xsl:variable name="ele" select="name()" />
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
  <xsl:variable name="replacement-node" select="($file2//*[name()=$ele][@id=$id])[1]" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$replacement-node">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$replacement-node/text()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise><xsl:call-template name="ident" /></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You need to pass in the URL of the second file as parameter url-of-file. The first file is the standard input.